# query which creates missing rows based on anther table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have many forms that users fill out. Each form contains a list of questions. In this first table is the form id and the id's of the questions.

```
form_id   | question_id
1         | 1
1         | 2
1         | 3
2         | 4
2         | 5
```

This table has two forms one which has 3 questions and the other 2. I have a second table which has the answers that the users have given for the questions.

```
user_id   | form_id | question_id | answer
476       | 1       | 1           | "answer1"
476       | 1       | 3           | "answer2"
693       | 1       | 1           | "answer3"
693       | 1       | 2           | "answer4"
235       | 2       | 5           | "answer5"
```

In this example, 2 users have filled out form 1 and 1 user has filled in form 2. But none have filled in all the questions. Is it possible to write a query which combines the two tables and will give me the answers that the user have given including the questions that they didn't answer? I'd like the results to look like this.

```
user_id   | form_id | question_id | answer
476       | 1       | 1           | "answer1"
476       | 1       | 2           | NULL
476       | 1       | 3           | "answer2"
693       | 1       | 1           | "answer3"
693       | 1       | 2           | "answer4"
693       | 1       | 3           | NULL
235       | 2       | 4           | NULL
235       | 2       | 5           | "answer5"
```

The problem that I have when I use a left join like this

```
select * from template t
left join answers a on a.template_id = t.template_id
AND a.question_id = t.question_id
AND t.template_id = t.template_id;
```

is that the row that results is missing user_id.

Comment: Please post your query attempt so far. If you don't have one you should at least make an attempt. Look at what JOIN can do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the specified result can be returned by a query.

One way to achieve this is a join to an inline view, and an "outer join" operation to the second table.

The "trick" is getting a distinct list of user_id and form_id from the second table, using a query, for example:

```
SELECT user_id, form_id
  FROM second_table 
 GROUP BY user_id, form_id
```

And then using that query as an inline view (wrapping it in parens, assigning a table alias, and referencing it like it was a table in an outer query.

All that's required after that is an "outer join" to the second table.

For example:

```
SELECT r.user_id
     , q.form_id 
     , q.question_id
     , a.answer
  FROM first_table q
  JOIN ( SELECT p.user_id, p.form_id
           FROM second_table p
          GROUP BY p.user_id, p.form_id
       ) r
    ON r.form_id = q.form_id
  LEFT
  JOIN second_table a
    ON a.user_id = r.user_id
   AND a.form_id = r.form_id
   AND a.question_id = q.question_id
 ORDER
    BY r.user_id
     , q.form_id 
     , q.question_id
```

Note that the keyword "LEFT" specifies an outer join operation, returning all rows from the left side, along with matching rows from the right side. A typical "inner" join would exclude rows that didn't find a matching row from the table on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
      left join
```

something like:

```
        select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.form_id= table2.form_id
```

Comment: This query doesn't return the resultset specified by OP.

Comment: @spencer agreed: i did not intend to provide the working no_brainer code it was just a quick wink in the right direction. that is why it says "something like" you have provided a better solution

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @andy it was not meant as critics or request- it was just a quick answer to point in the right direction for details. i can remove it if its against any of stackE guidelines or anything i do not bother, i beleive it would have helped if Spencer did not provide a more elaborate answer. which is all good anyway

Comment: I understand the confusion - I've made this mistake as well. "to point in the right direction"... is more appropriate in a comment.

Comment: ok do you ask me to delete my very precious answer now? if yes i will obey :)